# Error 500 on some Spotify API search

Tags: spotify

Trying to fetch playlists on https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?limit=50&offset=50&q=portugal&type=playlist throws a 500 when trying to fetch same url with a different offset (like 0 or 100) throws a 200 with the right response. (There is a total of 175 playlists)

Comment: Thanks a lot Edwin, we're looking into it and we'll try to deploy a patch during the day. For future bug reports, we've got an issue tracker at http://github.com/spotify/web-api.

Comment: Just deployed the patch, so this should be fixed now. Thanks again!